# Why is this message coming when I am trying to send

Tags: transaction, wallet, address, address-reuse

[image: I am trying to send some iotas and this message keeps popping up. What am I doing wrong? How to find out which node to select in order to get transactions confirmed?]
I am trying to send some iotas and this message keeps popping up. What am I doing wrong? How to find out which node to select in order to get transactions confirmed?

Answer (score 2):

Check if you already made the transaction and if it is pending, if so just promote it instead of trying to create a new transaction. Other possibility is that you are trying to send to an address that has already been used.

If you **know** what you are doing and really need to ignore this advice you can use the CLI wallet https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app.